# Angular 2+ optional parameter (query)

Tags: angular, angular-router, query-string

My application will be accessed from outside with an url and because I need to identify between certain entities I need to provide an id parameter. The parameter can also be absent.

My problem is I have a **request of using a query parameter**. I saw a lot of solutions for when the user interacts with a certain element and he is redirected with optional parameters by using navigationExtras.

I tried to leave  path: 'login' and just add the query parameter but it gives me

> > Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login%3Fid%3D1'

Same goes for matrix parameters but with a different string between *login* and *id*.

I can use this as a solution, but it will make me duplicate all of my routes and also it doesn't match the request of having query parameters.

```
{
  path: 'login',
  redirectTo: 'login/',
},
{
  path: 'login/:id',
  component: LoginComponent,
},
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What you are providing in your answer is a Route Parameters. `login/:id` . When you try to access the `:id` value, you'd get it from: `activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']` and it will match any route: `login/123`, `login/234`, `login/someRandomString`.

On the other hand, `queryParams` is appended as `queryString` to the end of the URL. `login?query1=something&query2=somethingElse`. Here, `query1` and `query2` are called Query Params.

To append `queryParams`:

`this.router.navigate(['/login], {queryParams: {
        query1: 'something',
        query2: somethingElse
});`

or

`<a [routerLink]="['/login']" [queryParams]="{query1: something, query2: somethingElse}">Router Link to Login</a>`

Comment: Is that the only way to append queryParams? My problem is I need to have the query already in the url and be treated when I open the application. I can't navigate anywhere

Comment: Then I don't really know. Maybe there's a way, maybe not. In theory, there's not a way to append a queryParams BEFORE your app is ran.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Child components, have a root component that redirects to login and a sibling component with the ID that redirects to the login component with the ID

`{
  path: 'login',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'login/',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: ':id',
      component: LoginComponent,
    }
]`

Comment: This is basically my snipped. I am looking for a way of declaring and interpreting query params when the app starts